# Custom routing for GET/POST/DELETE does not match

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

What I'm trying to do is to use similar route template in my custom route as the default route template uses, but getting 405 - METHOD NOT ALLOWED.

First one matches the GET request @ `api/accounts/abc123/contacts` but that's about it. Other two don't match, where as the default route @ `api/{controller}/{id}` matches all four verbs.

**EDIT: Updated route definitions**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ContactsApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id1}/contacts"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AddressesApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id2}/addresses"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "CoverageApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id3}/coverage"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "AccountsApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id4}/accounts"
);
```

I'm trying to map above routes to below actions:

**EDIT: Updated with {id1} parameter as per above route definition.**

```
[HttpGet]
public List<Contact> GetContacts(string id)
{
    return accounts.GetContacts(id);
}

[HttpPost]
public void PostContacts(string id1, [FromBody]IEnumerable<Contact> contacts)
{
    bool success = accounts.AssignContacts(id, contacts);
}

[HttpDelete]
public void DeleteContacts(string id1, [FromBody]IEnumerable<Contact> contacts)
{
    bool success = accounts.RemoveContacts(id, contacts);
}
```

I just want to keep my routes consistent...

Answer (score 1):

You only need to have the one route to match the actions given above:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiContacts",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/contacts"
);
```

Because your actions start with the relevant http verb, the corresponding action will be called.

Comment: It only works if you use different names other than {id} fot the parameter in the action signature. Otherwise the error is "Multiple actions matched the route"..

Comment: My above comment is true only if the default route is there (which needs to be there) - api/{controller}/{id}..

Comment: I've tested this out and it works for me. Have you got any other actions on the controller other than those shown above?

Comment: I've updated route definitions and action methods; this way they work, but I don't want to use {id1}, {id2} etc. named parameters if at all possible.. Instead it should be only {id}.